# Let me edit tags even when there is pending suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, tags, suggested-edits

I went to remove some tags from a question and normally I have enough rep to do this.

However, on this occasion, it appears that someone with not enough rep tried and instead I could approve an edit to do the same thing, but this wasn't enough.  In other words, I was prevented from removing tags by someone trying to do the same thing but not enough rep.

This struct me as a bit complicated.  If I can remove tags, perhaps I should be able to remove them even if someone with not enough rep has already tried to remove them.

Comment: You mean there is a  pending edit suggestion? Just wait until the suggestion has been rejected or approved, *or* use the 'improve' feature.

Comment: When you say "tried to approve the edit but this wasn't enough" what do you mean?

Comment: hmm .. couldn't you improve the edit and then change whatever you like?

Comment: I have never seen/noticed the `improve` option. I will look for it next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a tag-edit specific issue, this is a limit of the editing system.  However the change from earlier this year made it more apparent because the re-tag privilege was removed so 500+ rep users now need to suggest tag edits.

A pending suggested edit of any kind will not permit any other edits (suggested or regular) from being made (there are exceptions for regular edits when you started editing before the suggested edit was made).

This is necessary to prevent edit conflicts.  What if a suggested edit made a few changes, and while it was pending, someone came in and completely rewrote the post, making significant changes to clean up a bad post.  When the suggested edit gets approved, the major edit would have been overwritten, and the user who made the major edit might not even be aware of it.

In the end, you have 2 options:

1. Wait for the edit to be approved.  On SO the edit queue moves quickly, so it should only be a matter of minutes.  Obviously you can help it along by approving it if you have the necessary privileges.
2. If you have 2K rep, you can click "Improve" to approve the edit and them make some additional (and necessary fixes)

However, if the suggested edit is removing the tag and didn't leave anything else wrong, then what's the big deal?  The tag will get removed when/if the edit is approved.  Just keep any eye on the edit to make sure it does get approved.