# Let me do a retroactive edit even if I've already reviewed the pending suggested-edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Currently, when I click the `edit(1)` button from the post-menu, it opens up a box that allows me to review the suggested edit. If I've already reviewed the edit elsewhere, such as from the queue itself, it just says "*You have already reviewed this item. It needs more reviews from other users to be completed.*" And it doesn't allow me to edit the post.

There've been a couple of complaints about this in the past.

- [Let me edit tags even when there is pending suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199704/let-me-edit-tags-even-when-there-is-pending-suggested-edit)
- [Please allow tag editing when question is waiting for pending edit votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80182/please-allow-tag-editing-when-question-is-waiting-for-pending-edit-votes)
- [Unable to edit posts with pending edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78065/unable-to-edit-posts-with-pending-edits)
- [Why were edit suggestions designed to sometimes hinder the community's ability to edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79149/why-were-edit-suggestions-designed-to-sometimes-hinder-the-communitys-ability-t?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But they're mostly tagged as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) because of the shiny 'Improve' or 'Reject and Edit' buttons. This isn't helpful all the time, though: imagine that I simply approved or rejected an edit at the time, but later, after having reviewed it, found another relevant tag to add. Or, imagine that an OP made significant clarifications in comments that could be edited into the question. Or something. It's annoying that I have to wait for someone else to review it before I can make my changes.

It's particularly annoying on sites like Hinduism.SE, where the suspension of a few high-rep users has resulted in our only having two consistent reviewers. When we disagree on an edit, the suggestion may get stuck in the queue for [over a month](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/38175). And that sucks.

So, a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): **Allow me to do retroactive edits even if I've already reviewed the pending suggested-edit.**

(If there's a good reason for this restriction, perhaps it could be an option available only for higher-rep users, say 3k/7.5k.)

---

Turns out, [there *is* a workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131157/im-allowed-to-rollback-a-post-that-has-a-pending-suggested-edit)- performing a 'Rollback' through the revision history. It's not always* a possibility, but nice to know about...